# CLI/C# passing std::vector<> struct data to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have the following in c++

```
class TrimInfo
{
public:
    std::string LineName;
    std::string OrigImagePath;
    double Width;
    double Height;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<TrimInfo> TrimInfoPtr;

void SomeFunction();

bool DoSomethingElse(std::vector<JunkInfoPtr> &junkinfo, int *count);

bool SetTrimInfo(std::string ModelName, std::string PieceName, std::vector<TrimInfoPtr> trimInfo);
```

in the C# code I have

```
namespace BatchMergeAPI
{
    public partial class BatchMergeInterface
    {
    public struct TrimInformation
    {
        public string LineName;
        public string OrigImagePath;
        public double Width;
        public double Height;
    };

    public bool SetTrimInfo(string ModelName, string PieceName, List<TrimInformation> trimInfo)
    {

       return true;
    }
   }
}
```

now back in the c++ code to pass the info to C# I've done this but getting an error on the til->Add(ti) which says

> BatchMergeWrapper.cpp(52): error C2664: 'void System::Collections::Generic::List::Add(BatchMergeAPI::BatchMergeInterface::TrimInformation)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'BatchMergeAPI::BatchMergeInterface::TrimInformation ^' to 'BatchMergeAPI::BatchMergeInterface::TrimInformation'

I understand the error but not sure how to correct.

```
bool BatchMergeWrapper::SetTrimInfo(std::string modelName, std::string pieceName, std::vector<TrimInfoPtr> trimInfo)
{
System::String^ mn = gcnew System::String(modelName.c_str());
System::String^ pn = gcnew System::String(pieceName.c_str());

List<BatchMergeInterface::TrimInformation> ^til = gcnew List<BatchMergeInterface::TrimInformation>();

for (unsigned i = 0; i < trimInfo.size(); ++i)
{
    BatchMergeInterface::TrimInformation^ ti = gcnew BatchMergeInterface::TrimInformation();

    ti->Height = trimInfo[i]->Height;
    ti->Width = trimInfo[i]->Width;
    ti->LineName = gcnew System::String(trimInfo[i]->LineName.c_str());
    ti->OrigImagePath = gcnew System::String(trimInfo[i]->OrigImagePath.c_str());

    til->Add(ti);
}

return  _private->batchmergeAPI->SetTrimInfo(mn, pn, til);
}
```

Thanks for any help, I'm tied of looking at all the List examples.

Comment: you need `List<BatchMergeInterface::TrimInformation^>^` in the C++/CLI part

Answer (score 1):

You are missing two `^`:

```
List<BatchMergeInterface::TrimInformation^> ^til = gcnew List<BatchMergeInterface::TrimInformation^>();
```

Comment: When I do that I get an error telling me that "BatchMergeInterface::TrimInformation ^" is not a valid generic argument.

Compiling gives
BatchMergeWrapper.cpp(41): error C3225: generic type argument for 'T' cannot be 'BatchMergeAPI::BatchMergeInterface::TrimInformation ^', it must be a value type or a handle to a reference type
1>BatchMergeWrapper.cpp(41): error C3225: generic type argument for 'TInput' cannot be 'BatchMergeAPI::BatchMergeInterface::TrimInformation ^', it must be a value type or a handle to a reference type
BatchMergeWrapper.cpp(55): error C2664: cannot convert argument 3